# how to get seekbar data to set speed for View flipper

Tags: android

How can I get the input from the seekbar in the first activity to set the seep of the view flipper in the second activity?
I am completly doing this wrong or do i need a set onclick listener for the seekbar?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

SeekBar seekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(10);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.button);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view){
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SlideShow.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
public class SlideShow extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_show);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)this.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(seekBar.getProgress());
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();
}}
```

Comment: Hi, please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html on how to start another activity and pass a value to it. Your SlideShow activity will then need to retrieve this value.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction I still cannot pass the value to set the viewflipper speed. Are there special methods for calling the variable for the seek bar?

Comment: public class SlideShow extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_show);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int progress = intent.getExtras().getInt("progress");
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)this.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(progress);
        viewFlipper.startFlipping();
    }
}

Comment: in your onClick method for the seekbar, obtain the value of the seekbar first then set it in the intent using setExtra before startActivity(intent)